# PowerShell Active Directory IF statements

Tags: powershell, csv

In my organization, we spend a large amount of time changing user home folder paths, based on users changing roles, etc. I have written a very simple powershell script that sets the homedir path from a csv.:

```
Import-Csv C:\Dir\homedir.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName –HomeDirectory $_.HomeDirectory
}
```

What I would like for this to also do, is to check the users for the presence of a -profilepath (roaming profile) and change that (if present) to `"$_.HomeDirectory"\Profile` (all roaming profiles follow this construct).  If not present, it would simply skip down to the next user and perform the work as required.

I've played around with `if` statements, and really done more harm than good.  Anyone got a lifeline they can throw me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell where you're getting stuck, but I assume it's in the 'properties' bit. ProfilePath is not pulled by default when you issue the command `Get-ADUser`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
Import-Csv C:\Dir\homedir.csv | ForEach-Object {

    $user = Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -Properties 'ProfilePath'

    if($user.ProfilePath -ne $null)
    {
        $profilepath = $_.HomeDirectory + "\Profile"
        Set-ADUser $user –ProfilePath $profilepath
    }
    Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName –HomeDirectory $_.HomeDirectory
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `-Properties ProfilePath` if you want the `Get-ADUser` command to return the profile path.

```
$user = Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -Properties ProfilePath
If ($user.ProfilePath -ne $null) {
    Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -ProfilePath "$($_.HomeDirectory)\Profile"
}
```